# Convert bytes to hexadecimal string in solidity

Tags: solidity, string, bytes

In a smart contract I have stored a `bytes4` value: `0xa22cb465`. I'd like to parse this value as a string:

`string memory test = "0xa22cb465"`

I've only stumbled upon explanations on how to convert bytes to string, not parse. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly by "parsing" you mean going from an integer representation (*i.e.,*  `bytes4 data = 0xa22cb465;`) to a string representation in hexadecimal (*i.e.,* `string memory test = "0xa22cb465"`).

In that case, you'd need to write a function to actually do that conversion. Here is an example working with bytes input and base 16 string output with "0x" prefix.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

contract Example {
    bytes4 public data = 0xa22cb465;

    function howToUseIt() public view returns (string memory) {
        return iToHex(abi.encodePacked(data));
    }

    function iToHex(bytes memory buffer) public pure returns (string memory) {

        // Fixed buffer size for hexadecimal convertion
        bytes memory converted = new bytes(buffer.length * 2);

        bytes memory _base = "0123456789abcdef";

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
            converted[i * 2] = _base[uint8(buffer[i]) / _base.length];
            converted[i * 2 + 1] = _base[uint8(buffer[i]) % _base.length];
        }

        return string(abi.encodePacked("0x", converted));
    }
}
```

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

to convert from `bytes` to `string` simply do the following:

```
bytes data = 0xa22cb465;
string test = string(data);
```

The value `0xa22cb465` is not a UTF-8 character, so you'll get an error when attempting to convert it to string. Use the simple code below for testing.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

contract typeCasting{

    // hi = 0x6869;

    function bytesToString(bytes memory _data) public pure returns (string memory) {
        string memory result = string(_data);
        return result;
    }
}
```

all the best!